# Grails params map as java.util.HashMap

Tags: grails, request, httprequest, parameters, grails-2.0

In my grails project, can I use params map (object of GrailsParameterMap) as java.util.HashMap
 on application level ?

I want to do this for using Serializability of java.util.HashMap.
I can use `params as java.util.HashMap` everywhere in the code. But how can i achieve this on application level ?

I am using grails 1.3.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you tell more specifically what you're trying to accomplish? Like an example or something?

Comment: Actually, I do save this params map in http session and I am also using session replication among the application servers. So I get NotSerializableException on class GrailsParameterMap. Thats why I want to use params as java.util.HashMap which is Seralizable whereas GrailsParameterMap is not Serializable.

Comment: Putting the params in the session is just a bad idea in general. The HttpServletRequest is designed to be short lived.  For a single request.  Thus, params serve the same purpose.  If you need to keep data longer than that, then pull the data out of the params and put them in an object you can store in the session.

Answer (score 2):

Well, following @Gregg suggestion, of pulling the data out of the params map into an object, you can do it like this:

```
Map paramsMap = new HashMap()

params.each {key, value ->
  paramsMap.put(key, value)
}
```

And save this HashMap in the session. I hope it helps.

Comment: I do repeat my question. I want it on application level. I dont want to write the follwing code everywhere I save params in session. Instead below code, I can simply use params as java.util.HashMap       
Map paramsMap = new HashMap()
params.each {key, value ->
  paramsMap.put(key, value)
}

Comment: @user1180463 Then put it in a utility function. What does "I want it on application level" mean? Do you think there might me a switch in grails that makes the params object a HashMap that is suitable for your purposes? That would be kind of weird.